# PPPoE termination

Tags: cisco, pppoe

I am in need of something to use for terminating PPPoE sessions for my dsl and ftth customers. I need to support around 3000 customers and be expandable to more when the time comes. What would you guys recommend?

Answer (score 1):

A Cisco 7200 + a server with freeradius. Or you can go with a 7600 series...

Answer (score 0):

Juniper ERX can handle thousands of PPPoE sessions via the BRAS functionality.

Or take a look at [openl2tpd](http://www.openl2tp.org/home).

If an upstream provider is going to handle the LAC (PPPoE termination) then you actually only need to focus on the LNS & Radius integration.